# Hyper-V: Make a script that pulls last 6 digits of computer name, converts it to hex, then inserts as VM's MAC address (Last 8 digits)

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, mac-address

I am currently using Hyper-V and I want to change the static MAC Address into the last 6 digits of the computer name. MAC Addresses are in Hex. The computer name is a combination of random letters and random numbers generated by another script.

So far I have this:

```
$lastSixChar = $env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring($env:COMPUTERNAME.Length - 6)
$convertHex = $test | Format-Hex
```

This simply takes the name of the computer and converts it into hex. I'm not really sure if this is the smartest way to do this for actually pulling the hex, but at least it prints the correct number. I don't really know how I'm supposed to go about using the information I pulled and putting it into the last 8 digits of the MAC in Hyper-V.

Anything helps! Thanks

Edit:
Found this: Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName SRV01 -StaticMacAddress “00112233445566"

Comment: [1] where did `$Test` come from? [*grin*]  [2] your `$ConvertHex` var will have a `ByteCollection` object, not a hex string. [3] how do you intend to generate the prefix part of the MAC value?

Comment: I had forgotten to remove it from previous script. I'm not quite sure yet. I believe Microsoft uses its own prefix of 00-15 for all their VMs. I'm still trying to figure out how to insert a mac address into Hyper-V through Powershell. Looking like I'll need to download some Hyper-V tools to our management server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i presume that is referring to item [1] [*grin*] ... so, what about the 2nd & 3rd items?

Comment: I have edited my comment above

Comment: thank you for the added info! [*grin*] yes, you will need to have access to the correct powershell module to be able to use the cmdlet you listed. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted doesn't seem to make hex strings. so the following does that. [*grin*] since you did not post how to make the 1st two MAC address blocks, and have not responded to comments on that subject, i left that out.

i don't have any of the VM stuff, so i will leave your addition to your Question as the answer for that part of the problem.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
#    or use one of the AD or VM cmdlets and filter out all but the system name values
$SystemNameList = @'
pc1234567890
pc2a3s4d5f6g
pc3z4x5c6v7b
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($SNL_Item in $SystemNameList)
    {
    $HexList = @()
    # the "-replace" strips out all but the last 6 chars in the string
    foreach ($SB_Item in ($SNL_Item  -replace '.+(.{6})$', '$1').ToCharArray())
        {
        # this uses the string format operator to convert the int to hex
        $HexList += '{0:x0}' -f [int]$SB_Item
        }

    $HexList -join '-'
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
35-36-37-38-39-30
34-64-35-66-36-67
35-63-36-76-37-62
```